# Arduino memory leaks (SD card + strings)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, arduino

I'm playing around with writing strings to an [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) (that is triggered when a server connection is unavailable). It subsequently logs the sensor values to the SD card (within the regular `loop()` function) and once a connection to the server becomes available, it sends this as a packet over UDP.

I seem to be running into some pretty large memory leaks that occur once this SD card write section is entered, which eventually causes the Arduino to run out of free memory.

Comment: How did you determine you had a memory leak?  I suspect I might have a similar problem but I've yet to 'prove' it.  Was wondering how you came to your conclusion...

Comment: I used a free Ram peice of code and just printed it ever so often within my code.  What happened is it reduced till a point then crashed.

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/wUddCd8V](http://pastebin.com/wUddCd8V)

Comment: I found out there is a problem with the string function on arduino.  Avoid it.  Do not use it.

Comment: I tried using that RAM code earlier but with no avail (detecting leaks) with what I believe to be a simialr issue with the WiFiShield.   Shield works great UNLESS you disconnect/reconnect.  Gonna check the srouce code for it and look for strings per the advice here on this page...

Comment: What I did is printed the RAM value and then monitored it and saw it dropped every cycle

Comment: Understood.  That is what I would expect to see with my other issue, however I see RAM stay constant, then take a DIVE or hang before the next iteration.  Thus whatever is killing me is doing so violently...   Thanks for the insight into your problem!

Comment: Regarding the String class problem: There exists an (undocumented) method *reserve()* since 1.0 which lets you use strings more like buffers, which prevents some of the dynamic mem alloc probs on the Arduino without GC. It solved mem probs in my case. 
See http://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I read that code -- if you don't call close() for **every** case of an open you will have a leak -- there is only one file object (why I don't know).

Here is the interesting code:

```
void File::close() {
  if (_file) {
    _file->close();
    free(_file); 
    _file = 0;

    /* for debugging file open/close leaks
    nfilecount--;
    Serial.print("Deleted ");
    Serial.println(nfilecount, DEC);
    */
  }
}
```

They seem to have some nice code for finding leak right there... maybe you should try it.

Also just go and change the code at the end to look like this:

```
        dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
        // if the file is available, write to it:
        if (SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE)) 
        {
              dataFile.println(dataString);
              // print to the serial port too:
              Serial.println("data logged to SD");
        }
        // if the file isn't open, pop up an error:
        else
        {
              Serial.println("File Error datalog.txt");
        } 
        dataFile.close(); // always close after an open.
```

---

Well you don't show us the code for the SD object so it is a mystery but I expect you need to call dispose on something... maybe dataFile?

Comment: That would be in the SD library, 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d74i76rngbsa76w/UdxTS_gNxd

Comment: Thank you, I also found out there is a massive bug in one of the other libraries I am using, specifically the string one as the arduino doesn't have automated garbage collection so I have been told to rewrite everywhere I have used it and dump the library.

Comment: c and c++ don't have automated garbage collection since they are not managed languages.

Comment: As it turned out it was the String library causing the serious memory leaking - having removed it and replacing all uses with arrays of characters instead was laborious but it worked. Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: I could be wrong, but @Hogan do you need to close your if block with a close } just before the else?